# PostgreSQL Convert date (YYYY-WW) vs MySQL ('%x-%v')

Tags: mysql, postgresql, date-conversion

I'm trying to convert a query from MySQL to PostgreSQL. The results vary slightly as it appears there is a difference between how the two languages define a week out of the year and which days those include.

Same logic gives different date results:

PostgreSQL Syntax -

```
select date from sales where to_char(date, 'YYYY-WW') >= '2017-51' AND to_char(date, 'YYYY-WW') <= '2017-52'
```

MySQL Syntax -

```
select date from sales where 
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%x-%v') >='2017-51' and DATE_FORMAT(date, '%x-%v') <='2017-52'
```

When I query the PostgeSQL the results are `2017-12-17: 2017-12-24`.
MySQL results are `2017-12-18: 2017-12-25`.

Why is there a difference here?

Comment: You are comparing strings, not dates, in a very non-performant way. By forcing every date value to be converted to a string before comparison you force the server to make a full table scan, ignoring any indexes. If you *rewrite* the query so that the parameters are actual *dates*, you'll get orders of magnitude better performance

Comment: *Instead* of trying to convert the dates to strings, find the proper way for each database to calculate a date based on the year and week number, eg `to_date('201751', 'iyyyiw')` for Postgres, `STR_TO_DATE('201751', '%X%V')` for MySQL, eg : `select date from sales where date between to_date('201751', 'iyyyiw') and to_date('201752', 'iyyyiw')`

Comment: @VaoTsun that will still force a full table scan

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes - andnot related to question anyway - I'll delete comment - thank you

Answer (score 2):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-formatting.html

> WW week number of year (1-53) (the first week starts on the first day
>   of the year)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

> %v Week (01..53), where Monday is the first day of the week

so this behaviour is expected, because for postgres

```
t=# select to_char('2017-12-17'::date,'Day'), to_char('2017-12-17'::date,'WW');
  to_char  | to_char
-----------+---------
 Sunday    | 51
(1 row)
```

because:

```
t=# select to_char('2017-01-01'::date,'Day'), to_char('2017-01-01'::date,'WW');
  to_char  | to_char
-----------+---------
 Sunday    | 01
(1 row)
```

[while for MySQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4xmh5K47aFV4jKoqTmGKvv/0):

```
select DATE_FORMAT('2017-01-01', '%x-%v');
```

is

```
2016-52
```

and thus `2017-12-17`is week `50`